# PHP date formatting basic convert not working

Tags: php, datetime

Trying to convert date to mysql format: Y-m-d H:i:s

I know this is real basic and lots of other questions on the same subject but I have been stuck on this for a while now and can't figure out what I have wrong here.

```
<?php

$user_date = '07/06/2011 06:03';

//$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $user_date)));

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $user_date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

/* $oDate = new DateTime();
$oDate->createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $user_date);
$date = $oDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); */

if($date == '' || $date = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'){
    die('no-'.$date);
}       
die('yes-'.$date);
```

Comment: Your question doesn't clearly explain what is broken. What do you want the variable `$date` to contain?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini it is pretty obvious what is the intent

Comment: http://ideone.com/aN8ise It is working for me.

Comment: @MightyPork well yea now that he edited it. ;)

Comment: @John Magnolia could you accept the answer now, please?

Comment: @MightyPork sorry just done this, tried to do it yesterday but had the time limit restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies herein:

```
if($date == '' || $date = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'){
    die('no-'.$date);
}
```

You used single instead of double equals, hence the second "check" assigned the value, and returned it instead of comparing.

PHP considers non-empty string `true`, so the condition was met.

Comment: OMG I hate to think how many hours I have lost because of that.

Comment: I've developed the habit of `constant == $variable`, so as to avoid the assignment pitfall.  In this case, `'1970-01-01 00:00:00' = $date` would have illuminated this immediately.

Comment: @bishop I've seen that used and wondered why people do that. Thanks for clearing it up :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($user_date));
```